# Build newlib with existing cross Compiler

Tags: gcc, mips, newlib

I'd like to build the newlib library using a preinstalled cross compiler for mips (mips-linux-gnu-gcc). The compiler links the glibc by default.

```
$ mips-linux-gnu-gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=mips-linux-gnu-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc-cross/mips-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper
Target: mips-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr     --program-suffix=-5 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libitm --disable-libsanitizer --disable-libquadmath --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-mips-cross/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-mips-cross --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-mips-cross --with-arch-directory=mips --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --disable-libgcj --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --enable-multilib --with-arch-32=mips32r2 --with-fp-32=xx --enable-targets=all --with-arch-64=mips64r2 --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=mips-linux-gnu --program-prefix=mips-linux-gnu- --includedir=/usr/mips-linux-gnu/include
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9)
```

Now I'd like just to compile the newlib library using the mips compiler:

```
$ ../newlib-3.0.0.20180226/configure  --target=mips-linux-gnu --prefix=`pwd`                                                                                                 
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... mips-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln works... yes
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o  
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... no
checking whether mips-linux-gnu-gcc accepts -g... no
checking whether g++ accepts -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc... no
checking for gnatbind... no
checking for gnatmake... no
checking whether compiler driver understands Ada... no
checking how to compare bootstrapped objects... cmp --ignore-initial=16 $$f1 $$f2
checking for objdir... .libs
checking for isl 0.16, 0.15, or deprecated 0.14... no
recommended isl version is 0.16 or 0.15, the minimum required isl version 0.14 is deprecated
checking for isl 0.16 or 0.15... no
*** This configuration is not supported in the following subdirectories:
 target-newlib target-libgloss
(Any other directories should still work fine.)
checking for default BUILD_CONFIG... 
checking for --enable-vtable-verify... no
checking for bison... bison -y
checking for bison... bison
checking for gm4... no
checking for gnum4... no
checking for m4... m4
checking for flex... no
checking for lex... no
checking for flex... no
checking for makeinfo... makeinfo
checking for expect... no
checking for runtest... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for windres... no
checking for windmc... no
checking for objcopy... objcopy
checking for objdump... objdump
checking for readelf... readelf
checking for mips-linux-gnu-cc... no
checking for mips-linux-gnu-gcc... mips-linux-gnu-gcc
checking for mips-linux-gnu-c++... no
checking for mips-linux-gnu-g++... no
checking for mips-linux-gnu-cxx... no
checking for mips-linux-gnu-gxx... no
checking for mips-linux-gnu-gcc... mips-linux-gnu-gcc
checking for mips-linux-gnu-gcj... no
checking for mips-linux-gnu-gfortran... no
checking for mips-linux-gnu-gccgo... no  
checking for mips-linux-gnu-ar... mips-linux-gnu-ar
checking for mips-linux-gnu-as... mips-linux-gnu-as
checking for mips-linux-gnu-dlltool... no
checking for mips-linux-gnu-ld... mips-linux-gnu-ld
checking for mips-linux-gnu-lipo... no
checking for mips-linux-gnu-nm... mips-linux-gnu-nm
checking for mips-linux-gnu-objcopy... mips-linux-gnu-objcopy
checking for mips-linux-gnu-objdump... mips-linux-gnu-objdump
checking for mips-linux-gnu-ranlib... mips-linux-gnu-ranlib
checking for mips-linux-gnu-readelf... mips-linux-gnu-readelf
checking for mips-linux-gnu-strip... mips-linux-gnu-strip
checking for mips-linux-gnu-windres... no
checking for mips-linux-gnu-windmc... no
checking where to find the target ar... pre-installed
checking where to find the target as... pre-installed
checking where to find the target cc... pre-installed
checking where to find the target c++... pre-installed
checking where to find the target c++ for libstdc++... pre-installed
checking where to find the target dlltool... pre-installed
checking where to find the target gcc... pre-installed
checking where to find the target gcj... pre-installed
checking where to find the target gfortran... pre-installed
checking where to find the target gccgo... pre-installed
checking where to find the target ld... pre-installed
checking where to find the target lipo... pre-installed
checking where to find the target nm... pre-installed
checking where to find the target objcopy... pre-installed
checking where to find the target objdump... pre-installed
checking where to find the target ranlib... pre-installed
checking where to find the target readelf... pre-installed
checking where to find the target strip... pre-installed
checking where to find the target windres... pre-installed
checking where to find the target windmc... pre-installed
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
```

But nothing happens when I ran make afterwards:

```
$ make
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/qfi/newlib-build'
mkdir -p -- ./etc
Configuring in ./etc
configure: creating cache ./config.cache
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
configure: updating cache ./config.cache
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/qfi/newlib-build/etc'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/qfi/newlib-build/etc'  
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all-target'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/qfi/newlib-build'
```

When I set CC to mips-linux-gnu-gcc make is complaining about a missing --host option.
Is there something wrong with my building steps?

The task seemed to me at first straightforward but now I have no idea on how to make it work.

Comment: `--prefix=\`pwd\`` ... ugh, really? That will install it to the same directory as the build tree, which will make it difficult to untangle the installed files from the build artefacts. If you don't plan to install it, you can just leave out the `--prefix` option.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is shown here in the newlib config:

```
*** This configuration is not supported in the following subdirectories:
 target-newlib target-libgloss
```

That means it's not actually going to build newlib for the target!

I think the problem is that `mips-linux-gnu` is not a meaningful target for newlib, because that implies using glibc, and newlib doesn't want to depend on glibc.

I might be wrong, but I *think* you need to something like a  `mips-elf` cross-compiler to build newlib (I'm not sure about the target triplet, so check it!). So first configure GCC with `--target=mips-elf --without-headers --prefix=$PATH_WHERE_YOU_WANT_THE_CROSS_COMPILER` and only build the compiler (not its runtime libs), using `make all-gcc && make install-gcc`. Then you can use that GCC to build newlib (with `$PATH_WHERE_YOU_WANT_THE_CROSS_COMPILER/bin` is in your `$PATH`) using the same `--target`. Then you can build another GCC that uses the just-installed newlib.